# Getting error while Installing Cordova plugin

Tags: node.js, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am trying to add this plugin to my app: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-pdf-generator

I installed NPM as instructed in  https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/install-node-js-npm-windows. Then opened command prompt window and went to my app's folder. later i ran below commands in command prompt  "npm install cordova-pdf-generator".After that ran this: "cordova plugins add node_modules/cordova-pdf-generator"

While running cordova plugins add node_modules/cordova-pdf-generator i am getting cordova.js script error.Please help me!!

Thanks,
Raghu

Comment: This is tagged as Phone Gap Build. Please remove the tag. This is not a PGB issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those instructions seem... odd. After installing npm, you should only need to make a call to:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-pdf-generator --save
```

This should install the plugin from npm to your app, and add a line to your `config.xml` with the plugin info.

---

EDIT: thinking about the `npm` stuff some more, it looks like the author did some weird stuff to archive it. So... here's one way to get the plugin working. You've probably already called:

```
npm install cordova-pdf-generator
```

So that means you should have a subdirectory of the current directory named  `node_modules`. The next steps you need to take:

1. Create a cordova project:

   `cordova create MyProject`
2. Add the plugin to the project:

   `cd MyProject`

   `cordova plugins add ../node_modules/cordova-pdf-generator`

The creating of the project was needed for the plugin to be added to it. That step doesn't appear to be listed in the `cordova-pdf-generator` project on [npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-pdf-generator).

Comment: but this dint work for me @eb1. Still getting a red line error message as cc=urrent working directory is not a codova based application.

Comment: You need to call that from inside your application's directory.

Comment: Yes I did the same @eb1

Comment: OK - just added the extra steps needed (see the edit above). Hopefully that works for you! I've tried it on my machine and it did add the plugin.